# Can I make an Animator Controller state which does not control object's position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am starting to learn with Animator Controller. I have this little problem here.

I've made an animation for my playing cards to hover while being dragged (Hover state). Works nicely.

But I had a script that adjusts Z pos when the card is put down. The problem is that the animator overrides the position in an Idle state even though it is set to not control position in this state.

Can I somehow make a state in which animation is not controlled by AC?

I know I can override the animation in LateUpdate, but I want to adjust position only once and leave card to rest. The AC controls card position all the time in Idle.

Hover->Idle transition is set to No Exit Time and 0 Transition Duration.

I also tried leave Motion field empty, but got the same result.

While typing this question and reading relevant answers I came to a decision that I will adjust position of root container object for a card and leave the animations alone. I'll have to do some refactoring for that.

But I still wonder. Can I make a state which does not control the object position?

Comment: as soon as **any** state has only one single keyframe for a position the animator will always overrule the position. A workaround I usually go is using a parent object to position the entire thing and put the animator only on the child -> can animate **relative** positions but still move around the entire thing using the parent position

Comment: @derHugo This explains the situation. The Hover state has key frames for position and the Idle state does not, but it still controls the position putting object to it's default state. Thanks. You could have posted this as an answer ;)